# GRANT SELECT to Azure SQL system tables

Tags: azure-sql-database

Is there any possibility to set GRANT SELECT for db user to system tables in Azure SQL?

I need run Stored Procedure with select from system tables, something like this:

```
SELECT [something] 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(@dbName),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) AS ips
JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON (i.object_id = ips.object_id) AND (i.index_id = ips.index_id)
JOIN sys.objects AS o ON (o.object_id = ips.object_id)
```

Unfortunatelly, if I try execute this SP I got message that "The user does not have permission to perform this action."

Only way, that I found for perform this, is set user rolemember to db_owner, but this is quite security gap ...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure SQL Database, querying a dynamic management view requires VIEW DATABASE STATE permissions. The VIEW DATABASE STATE permission returns information about all objects within the current database. To grant the VIEW DATABASE STATE permission to a specific database user, run the following query:

```
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO database_user;
```